# IIS http request redirect with authentication

Tags: http, iis, authentication, redirect, httpwebrequest

I have two website, Site A and Site B.
Site A is on the DMZ area where allow public/anonymous sending http request (one of the client http request data), and i would like the request to redirect to Site B(internal secure host which only allow internal http request)

My question is, Site B is setup with basic authentication REALM. but public/anonymous http request doesn't support Basic REALM. is there a way in the IIS Site A to redirect the request with authentication so Site B could accept the request with REALM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to resolve the above question by using [Microsoft ISA Server](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/EP/ISA+Server+2006+as+Reverse+Proxy+for+SAP+Applications!!!)